# Perl: Replace string with/without "+" sign

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to replace parts of string. Currently I am using a simple method as follows:

```
my $text = $ARGV[0];
my $in_d = $ARGV[1]; 
my $out_d = "Sample_text";

$text =~ s/$in_d/$out_d/;
```

The above code does not seem to work if there is a '+' sign involved.
For e.g. for the code:

```
my $text = "I+here starving here";
my $input_d = "I\+here";
my $out_d = "I";
$text =~ s/$input_d/$out_d/;
print $text."\n";
```

Output:

```
I+here starving here
```

How do I make sure that the text gets replaced regardless of characters involved? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\Q`, `\E` sequence to escape block of characters.

```
\Qfoo+\E
```

So, it would be

```
$text =~ s/\Q$input_d\E/$out_d/;
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eU0gI9/1)

Comment: You could also use the function [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) for the same effect.